# Knapsack variant problem with topN solutions of fixed size

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic, knapsack-problem

I have a dynamic programming question. I'm trying to find a good-enough solution in python for a knapsack variant problem.

The additional requirements:

1. Instead of having just the best solution I'm looking for the best
   topN solutions.
2. I'm looking for solutions with exactly size S. i.e. the amount of items in the backpack must be S. Optionaly, if S is -1 we accept flexible sizes

So, I want to put in the knapsack S elements to find the most valuable subsequence of items that weighs no more than maxweight.
Each element has (value, weight), where the value is a number and weight is a non-negative integer. Maxweight is a non-negative integer.

Example:

```py
def knapsack_variant(items, maxweight, S=-1, topN=10):
    """
    >>> items = [(4, 12), (2, 1), (6, 4), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
    >>> maxweight = 15
    >>> S = 4
    >>> topN = 3
    >>> knapsack_variant(items, maxweight, S, topN)
    (11, [(2, 1), (6, 4), (1, 1), (2, 2)])
    next two solutions
    """
```

Comment: Sort them by Value/weight, start adding them in order is a decent heuristic to start with. What work have you done on this/ what have you tried?

Comment: I tried brute force, first combination and then apply filters, but it's not scalable to large sets.